# Flutter do work in background which is few seconds long (Flutter AsyncTask in Android)

Tags: dart, flutter

Is there any way to handle the background task (computational here) which is couple of seconds long without blocking the UI thread?

Here is the example (the following code blocks the UI and sometimes runs of of memory):

```
void _hangMiPhone() {
  List<int> list = [];
  for(int i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
    list.add(i);
  }
}
```

PS: This code is for simplicity and may not have any use case. I was looking for something like `AsyncTask` in Android

Comment: Analog of `AsyncTask` is `async` and `await`. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I know that. But my question is somewhat different. I think what I am looking for is isolates in dart.

Comment: you can try using https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/android_alarm_manager for running background tasks in android

Comment: @nonybrighto please read my question first, i am looking for something else.

Comment: see https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/compute.html - you cannot use `async` and `await` as your code does not use any `Future`s

Comment: @pskink I know async await but my question is something different.

Comment: did you see `compute()` function documentation? if so, whats unclear?

Comment: I didn't see that, let me try that out.

Answer (score 0):

For Flutter, use "compute".

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/background-parsing#4-move-this-work-to-a-separate-isolate

Example code:

```
Future<List<Photo>> fetchPhotos(http.Client client) async {
  final response = await client
      .get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'));

  // Use the compute function to run parsePhotos in a separate isolate.
  return compute(parsePhotos, response.body);
}
```

Flutter Foundation:
https://docs-flutter-io.firebaseapp.com/flutter/foundation/compute.html